# Cannot set .attr("placeholder", "text") with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attr

I am trying to set placeholder on a field that comes from a PHP request, but I have no success. Here is my code:

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
   <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
 </div>
 <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

and the output code in HTML is as follows:

```
<input type="password" name="cimy_uef_wp_PASSWORD" id="cimy_uef_wp_1" class="cimy_uef_input_27" value="" maxlength="100">
```

I am trying to select this with this jQuery function. It works in the console but not in the website itself:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  $( "#cimy_uef_wp_1" ).attr("placeholder","Password*");
});
```

Comment: The code [works](https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/esucayav/). Is the form present in the page from the start, or is it loaded through AJAX ?

Comment: I also check the code in the console and it worked, but only in the console. The form is not present in the page from the start. PHP generate it with this request from an external WordPress website: <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('form').find("#cimy_uef_wp_1").each(function(ev)
  {
      if(!$(this).val()) { 
      $(this).attr("placeholder", "Password*");
  }
  });
});
```

Copy and paste this code in your js file, this will change all placeholder text from whole site. Or, add the jQuery so that it runs after the form:

```
 <form>
   ...
 </form>
 <script>
    $( "#cimy_uef_wp_1" ).attr("placeholder","Password*");
 </script>
```

Comment: oMiKey thank you for the effort. Your code works in the console but again not in the website. I think the problem is because the form is generated with PHP request. Maybe it loads after the jQuery... I don't know. Very strange problem :(

Comment: I think you may have to add the placeholder using php

Comment: would be great but unfortunately I don't have access to the PHP... will need to find a way with the JS :) once again, thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your sw create dybamically the element with an ajax call. If this is the case and the global option to the ajax call is not set to false you may use something like:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, jqXHR, settings) {
   if ($("#cimy_uef_wp_1").length > 0) {  // the element is ready
      $("#cimy_uef_wp_1").attr("placeholder","Password*");
   }
});
```